# Is it possible to use alt-XYZ shortcuts on Excel on OS X?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2011

I don't want to know the equivalents -- I want to use the same commands. I'm switching between windows at work and a mac at home.

Comment: @Karan but i want folks watching the general tags to see my question too, not just the specific version tags

Comment: Ok, but what I meant was that you didn't mention the Mac Excel version at all, so I guessed on your behalf. The specific version *may* come into play so it's always better to mention it somewhere at least.